# Duplicate Reachbility class in 2 compiled frameworks/libraries

Tags: objective-c, cordova, reachability

We've got an issue where Reachability is being included in a Framework (PhoneGap) and also in a 3rd party compiled library (*.a file) from what i can see i can't easily change this scenario, but wondered whether there was any way of telling xCode to take preference of one over the other, or somehow avoiding the clash of these 2 symbols?

Any help much appreciated!

Matt